# How to set the display scale of a Java app from PC

Tags: java, scale, resolution

I'm making an app in Java, and I have a problem with resolution. PCs come with the resolution 1920x1080 and with scale 100%, but laptops come with scale 125% and the app display like shown below. How can I adapt the JFrame according of resolution and scale of each PC?

[image: screen with scale 100%]

[image: screen with scale 125%]

```java
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice device = env.getScreenDevices()[0];
    DisplayMode oldMode = device.getDisplayMode();
    DisplayMode newMode = new DisplayMode(1536,864,oldMode.getBitDepth(),oldMode.getRefreshRate());
    device.setDisplayMode(newMode);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change display mode
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsDevice.setDisplayMode(GraphicsDevice.java:432)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.setDisplayMode(Win32GraphicsDevice.java:452)
```

Comment: Fonts might scale slightly different from rectangles and such. (Maybe I am wrong in that respect.) And there might be font substitution at work. And you might be still using swing. Check that the label indeed has the full width of the text field, and adequate height reserve. First [`getDisplayModes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getDisplayModes())

Comment: What GUI framework are you using, as either it is not scale-aware, or you wrote it in a way it cannot take scale into account? As an aside, PCs don't necessarily come with resolution 1920x1080 and scale 100%. My PC has resolution 2560x1440 at scale 125%, and someone with bad eyesight and 1920x1080 might also set a higher scale.

Comment: An app trying to set the scale of a display would be a bad idea. Users don't like it when you mess with their preferences.

Comment: I'm using AWT, so how could i fix this without changing their preferences, what command should i use to change the size of Jframe and the components without compromising the design